# Connecting to DB2 through PHP

Tags: php, db2

I'm trying to connect to a DB2 databse from a windows machine using XAMPP.

When I try to load the php_ibm_db2 module I get the following error

"PHP Startup: ibm_db2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match"

How do I fix this and connect to a db2 database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you are trying to use an old *(it seems : it's from 2006)* version of the `imb_db2` .dll file, with a recent *(it's from 2009)* version of PHP. You should use the same version for both PHP and the extension.

There is a recent version of some extensions .dll available from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ ; amongst those, there is a couple of versions of `php_ibm_db2.dll` 1.8 ; with a bit of luck, maybe they'll match your version of PHP -- and there are versions for both PHP 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: I used one of those versions and put it in the ext directory where PHP is looking for extensions.

I now get this error

"PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll' - The specified module could not be found."

I've restarted XAMPP, double checked to make sure the module is in that directory (it is).

Why isn't it being found?

Comment: Humph, not good (and I don't have any windows machine here, so I can't test by myself) ;; did you use the version (i.e. ts vs non-ts that matches your version of PHP ? )

Comment: Oh :-( Sorry, then, I can't help you much more ; maybe you'll have more luck with another answer... Good Luck !

Comment: "module could not be found" is Windows' lovely little way of telling you there's a runtime dependency (DLL) missing. Use a tool like Dependency Walker to open C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll and see what the missing DLL is - there's usually a 'client library' component to these (libpq for PgSQL, libmysqlclient for MySQL, dblib for MSSQL, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You have different "versions":
20060613
and
20090626

Did you compile these by yourself? Re-compile it.

Comment: Whoops, I should read more carefully. Your versions does not match.
How do you load the module?

Answer (score 0):

The top answer got close but didn't have the right php_ibm_db2.dll I needed for PHP 5.3.2 VC9 (windows) NTS (non-thread-safe). But I found one that has it - and many more! Link:

[PHP IBM DB2 DLLs on SourceForge via Technology Explorer for DB2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/files/IBM_DB2%20PHP%20Driver%20for%20Windows/)